# How can I use the Tab bar in the middle of the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPAAP.png)

I get this error when I use TabBarView.RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderColoredBox#63150 relayoutBoundary=up2 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TabBar'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 200,
              ),
              TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.list,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.grid_view,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Text('ListPage'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text('GridPage'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Text('ListPage'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text('GridPage'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

When I use it, the tab bar is no longer displayed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4sKB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 3,
                  initialIndex: 0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TabBar(
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Example 1',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Example 2',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Example 3',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TabBarView(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Tab View 1',
                            
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Tab View 2',
                              
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Tab View 3',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: preview]